# How to start with WebTorrent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, webtorrent

I have some idea for [WebTorrent](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent). I have some experience with JavaScript and jQuery, but I never use Node.js or Browserify. Could someone explain me how to use the following simple code?

```
var client = new WebTorrent()

var torrentId = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6a9759bffd5c0af65319979fb7832189f4f3c35d'

client.add(torrentId, function (torrent) {
  // Torrents can contain many files. Let's use the first.
  var file = torrent.files[0]

  // Display the file by adding it to the DOM. Supports video, audio, image, etc. files
  file.appendTo('body')
})
```

Should I attach a `<script src="webtorrent.min.js"></script>` and convert the code from above by Browserify (`browserify app.js > bundle.js`)? Or maybe I need to use `npm install webtorrent` and attach some Browserify code?

After using the code `npm install webtorrent` and just doing <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd>, this example from above in `<script>` tag showed up player. Magic :) But I do something in my VM and now Chrome say that the `require('webtorrent')` is not definied.

It would be great if I could use WebTorrent as simple as jQuery.

Comment: If you use the standalone js file (`<script src="webtorrent.min.js"></script>`), you don't need browserify or require.

Answer (score 3):

With the code you posted, you don't need to require. If you use the standalone minified version, you can use use `var client = WebTorrent()`and start using it.

Here's an old example: http://jsfiddle.net/fr090taa/ when I answered this: [How to use webtorrent.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082637/how-to-use-webtorrent-io/34082926#34082926)

Don't use node/npm/browserify. Just use the minified version.

Check https://github.com/DiegoRBaquero/BTorrent (there's also a clean compiled version to view in JS instead of Coffee)

I'm a WebTorrent project contributor.

Comment: Thx. So Webtorrent is very simple in use :) How about Webtorrent-hybrid? There is no standalone version, and I have to use all peers. I must install webtorrent-hybrid in node? Wrtc (unfortunately) is big problem, especially on Azure.

Comment: webtorrent-hybrid imho is broken. There's nothing bridging the two torrenting networks yet that works as it should.

Comment: Is there any alternative for bittorrent-hybrid? I would like to use bittorrent, not webtorrent. I do not need a hybrid solution, just bittorrent.

Comment: For the time being, no. The thing is, if you want to use BitTorrent you can, in the browser, only with extensions; not purely as one would like.